# formik how to trigger submit from outside

Tags: reactjs, formik

I got a form like this

```
const SubtitleForm = ({ sub }) => {
    const formik: any = useFormik({
        initialValues: sub,
        onSubmit: async (values) => {
            const res = await update(values)
        },
    })
    return (
        <form className="subtitleFormComponent">
            <input
                className="subtitle"
                autoComplete="off"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.name}
            />
        </form>
    )
}
export default SubtitleForm
```

How can I trigger submit from outside this form / component ?

Comment: Do you mean a parent component?

If you do, I think a better approach is to the parent component to have the input and the submit buttons as children. 

And then using useFormikContext hook, you can trigger the submit in the parent.

Comment: good idea......

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to have the submit button in a different component to the fields; I'd suggest to wrap both in the form. Then, you can use the `useFormikContext` in the inputs to update the data, and in the submit button.

A POC of the idea:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-chebyshev-5nonm?file=/src/App.js

EDIT:
If someone need it, using `useRef` will allow you to submit from outside the `<Formik>` tag:

```js
...
 const formRef = useRef(null);
...
const handleSubmit = ()=> {
  formRef.current?.handleSubmit();
}
...
<Formik
  innerRef={formRef}
  initialValues={sub}
  onSubmit={...}
>
...
</Formik>
<button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
```

Here's a demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-submit-button-outside-the-form-fqcxrr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Good concept, but your submit button is still inside the Formik tag

Comment: @zepol.j thanks for pointing it out. I've update the answer to provide that solution